# Strange redirection behaviour allowing output truncation

Tags: c, file, unix

We have a build script which builds an embedded system for a number of board types and, when capturing the output one way, it seems to work okay. The other way, it gets partially through the output then truncates the file before continuing.

The way that works:

```
time ( cd ~ ; builder.sh 2>&1 | tee ~/builder.out )
```

And the way that seems to truncate:

```
time ( cd ~ ; builder.sh > ~/builder.out 2>&1 )
```

The truncation appears to happen at a very specific point, the first line in the file after truncation is always `DEFAULT_INCDIRS=...` from `qmake`. The fact that it's at a specific point in the process rather than when the file reaches a certain size seems to indicate it's not some external file checker doing the truncation.

In any case, if it were deleted, the script would continue to write to the inode of the deleted file until it was closed, then it would remove said inode.

What actually happens is that the file seems to be truncated and then writing continues at the start. But I know of no way to do this without the program actually having access to the file handle itself.

In *both* cases above, the builder script does not actually know about its output file, it simply writes both output and error messages to `stdout` and lets the shell redirection take care of it.

So my questions are these: is there a way to do this in the UNIX model of file I/O (say from C file API calls)? In other words, can you truncate a file you are writing to when it's been set up via redirection? Why does the `tee` variant work? What prevents it from being truncated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So yeah, somebody is clearly calling `lseek()` or `ftruncate()` on `stdout` as you've already noticed.

To track down the offender, `strace -f` will certainly help. When doing something as exotic as this you may need to do `strace -f sh -c 'build.sh 2>&1 | cat > output' > log 2>&1` because it will happily gobble your strace output too otherwise.

Once you have the log, locate the call to `lseek(1,`, `lseek(2,`, `ftruncate(1,`, or `ftruncate(2,`. From there, search backwards to the previous `exec` and you should know.

One program that legitimately does games with `stdout` is `cdrecord`, of which at least some versions want your CD burner on standard output.

Comment: Our build process takes 40min per board, I'm not sure we have the capacity to store 40mins worth of strace, but I'll see what I can find :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Use ssh and stream it somewhere else like your workstation if you have to.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it turns out that programs *can* seek on standard output (though I wonder at the sanity of programs that do so).

The following program illustrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    for (int i = 3; i > 0; --i) {
        //rewind(stdout);
        printf("Hello, world %d !\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Run this capturing the output and you'll end up with a file containing:

```
Hello, world 3 !
Hello, world 2 !
Hello, world 1 !
```

However, if you uncomment the `rewind` line, you'll only end up with the *final* line in the output file.

Interestingly enough, since I have no control over the program truncating `stdout`, this may actually be a useful use cat for the "useless use of cat" award. Instead of executing:

```
myprog >outfile 2>&1
```

and having `myProg` truncate the file, I can instead do:

```
myprog 2>&1 | cat >outfile
```

and the pipeline will protect the `cat` output file from the truncation.

---

In terms of the actual question, it appears that `qt5base` (part of `buildroot`) is playing some sort of shenanigans with the output file handle for some reason. We've solved it by using the `cat` method above since we haven't got the time to chase up buildroot (or create patch files) to get it fixed properly.

Comment: You might also try `myprog >> outfile 2>&1` . Most shells implement this by opening outfile in append-only mode, in which all writes are forced to be at the end of the file regardless of what lseek has done.